# Three.js ply loader - object not rendered properly

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js

I'm a beginner to three.js and I'm using Angular 13 with three.js v0.137.0.
I'm trying to load and preview a ply file from a data URL. When the object is rendered, it is only showing like lines as in the screenshot. [screenshot - how the ply file renders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae4xT.png).

I imported the .ply file that I'm trying to preview from the editor at [https://threejs.org/editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) and it loads the same .ply file perfectly. [how the file renders in three.js editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2PFb.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

```
public createScene(canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>, source: string): void {
const dataURL = `data:application/octet-stream;base64,${source}`;
this.canvas = canvas.nativeElement;

this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: this.canvas,
  alpha: true,    // transparent background
  antialias: true // smooth edges
});
this.renderer.setSize((window.innerWidth / 2), (window.innerHeight / 2));

this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

this.light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x443333);
this.light.position.z = 10;

this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000
);

this.camera.position.z = 0.5;
this.renderer.setSize((window.innerWidth / 2), (window.innerHeight / 2));
this.scene.add(this.camera);
this.scene.add(this.light);
if (source) {
  this.loader.load(dataURL, (geometry) => {
    geometry.center();
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 0.01, vertexColors: true } ));
    this.scene.add(this.mesh);
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 0.01, vertexColors: true } ));
```

Since you are loading a point cloud, it's not correct to create an instance of `THREE.Mesh`. Use `THREE.Points` instead.

There is also no need to call `computeVertexNormals()` when the geometry represents a point cloud.